# Catch if runtime.sendMessage doesn't receive response

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

Let's say we have a background script which communicates with the browser action popup.

Under certain conditions I want to send a message to popup. First, I need to get if popup is opened at all (where *chrome.extension.getViews({ type: "popup" })* can be used). Secondly, I want to send a message to that popup. The problem is that I want to place the *runtime.onMessage* listener in the popup only after certain async tasks, therefore what we'll get is that if the popup is opened and we will try to send a message there, it will produce an error since *runtime.sendMessage* method will try to send a message to the unset (yet) *runtime.onMessage* listener.

I couldn't find a way to catch that error because of the way it is handled in chrome API. Basically what I want is to be able to *catch* an error if I'm trying to send a message to the unset *runtime.onMessage* listener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be possible to catch the error by checking chrome.runtime.lastError inside the callback of sendMessage:

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('foo', data => {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    console.log('Yay');
  } else {
    // use data
  }
});
```

P.S. you probably don't need to use extension messaging when communicating between two extension pages such as the background script and the popup script because it's slow (it serializes to JSON internally). You can directly access the background script's `window` object and its global variables by using chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage or chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage in the popup script. You can also use [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel) API which utilizes the fast structured cloning algorithm that's capable of transferring a lot more object types than the JSON-based extension messaging.

Comment: Thanks, that's some interesting info. Would "chrome.runtime.lastError" give me the appropriate error or it could give me anything, that could not even be related to my sendMessage method? Would it also result in red error logs in the console?

Comment: Also, we can access the window object of the background script, to access the window object of the popup I should use the getViews method I've mentioned before? If I'm not mistaken, it gives us window object(s)... This is a good idea, but I think if the runtime.sendMessage/onMessage stuff is there, it should be used and it should be able to be used in different situations. :) I mean that it must provide us a good error handling mechanism, assuming that it is one of the main methods for communicating between pages.

Comment: 1) lastError gives an error only if it occurred in this API call, otherwise it's `undefined`. Checking lastError removes the error messages in console about the unhandled lastError, obviously because it's handled now 2) getBackgroundPage gives you the background page so it makes sense to use it in the popup, while getViews gives you all views not only the background page 3) For simple object types you can use extension messaging but for complex types it's a bad tool.

Comment: 1) Thanks, looks like I've underread the API docs. Good job, this should be an answer to my initial question! 2) Yeah, I get you, I meant that in background page we can use getViews to get the popup window object. 3) Thank you again, is the downside of extension messaging - the speed?

Comment: The downside is the overhead for serializing/deserializing via JSON which stresses CPU in case of big and deeply nested messages.